# Каким образом в консоли выводится -7?

Tags: c, циклы, for

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
       int i, j;
       for  (i = 0, j = 3; i < 10; i++, j--)
           printf ("%d", i);
           printf ("\n%d", j);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Вероятно, из-за забытых фигурных скобок?...

Comment: Да, действительно, но теперь выводится совсем по другому: не -7, а числа от 3 (включительно) до -7 (не включительно).

Comment: Потому что теперь ваш код выводит их именно так из-за наличия фигурных скобок

Comment: А какое поведение было ожидаемо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант: в цикле выводит i от 0 до 9, j при этом уменьшается до -7

```
for  (i = 0, j = 3; i < 10; i++, j--)
   printf ("%d", i);
   // Теперь выводится j = -7 - полученное на итерации, когда i равно 10
   printf ("\n%d", j);
```

Второй вариант...

```
for  (i = 0, j = 3; i < 10; i++, j--)
{
   printf ("%d", i);
   printf ("\n%d", j);
}
```

Выводятся пары чисел - возрастающее `i` от 0 до 9, и, соответственно, убывающее `j` от 3 до -6 (сумма `i+j` на каждой итерации равна 3 :))

Что заказано - то и выведено. О `\n` и "слипшемся" выводе промолчим.